# How to save a Bitmap Image?

Tags: python, tkinter, bitmap

*I am trying to make a QR code generator but it cannot save the bitmap image*
*This is the code

```
 qrImage= Qr.xbm(scale=6)
 global photo
 photo = BitmapImage(data= qrImage)
 showCode()
def showCode():
    global photo
    notificationLabel.config(image= photo)

def save():
    f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".bmp")
    if f is None:
        return
    text2save = photo
    f.save(text2save)
    f.close()
notificationLabel= Label(root)
notificationLabel.pack()
```

**It returns with this error**

```
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'save'
```

**Is there another way to save Bitmap Images or should I save it as a png?**

Comment: You can save any image in any format using [PIL](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

Comment: Did you try mode='wb'?

Comment: I have tried, but it returns with AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'save

Comment: You should use `mode='wb'`, and `f.write(photo)` instead of `f.save(...)`.

Comment: Now it says  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'BitmapImage'

Comment: Your code is not complete -- the definition of `BitmapImage` is missing. If it comes from an external module, check its documentation.

Comment: Then you should use `Pillow` (`PIL`) module instead.